# Swift NSDate create var with hour and minute only

Tags: swift, nsdate

I asked a question a moment ago about how to get the hour and minute of the current time and not worry about the year month day, and that question was solved. Im now trying to apply the same logic to creating a custom time (in the hour minute format) but im getting an error

i have

```
let time1 = NSDateComponents()
    time1.hour = 8
    time1.minute = 54

    let date1: NSDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(time1)!
```

I tried using the previous answer to make it look like

```
 let date1: NSDate = calendar.components([ .Hour, .Minute ], fromDate: time1())
```

but i get "ambiguous reference to member 'components'"

from there i remove the : NSDate...then im told to remove the () from the end....and i keep getting errors. Is there an easy fix to this?
Thanks

Comment: An `NSDate` represents a point in time, as a number of seconds since a reference date. (The reference date is 2001-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.) So an hour and a minute aren't enough to construct an `NSDate`. What do you want the year, month, and day to be?

Comment: oh i see, I dont want anything else besides the hour and minute, because the actual day isnt important for me. Im basically trying to see what time it is and as a result have the next time created show up first in a list...

Comment: You should probably just create your own `TimeOfDay` struct containing the hour and the minute.

Comment: I highly recommend watching [WWDC 2013: Solutions to Common Date and Time Challenges](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013-227/).

Comment: Im watching the video and I am up to the point where the speaker covers what I am trying to do. I still need help. Im only a student and am still learning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quick way, getting the nsdate from your string elements and then convert the nsdate back to a string if you want to :

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
let hour = 08
let minutes = 32
let time = formatter.dateFromString("\(hour):\(minutes)")!
let finalTime = formatter.stringFromDate(time)
print(time)
print(finalTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're not calling `NSCalendar`. Since you only want the hour and minutes, you could return a dictionary

```
func getHourMinutes(fromDate: NSDate) -> [String:Int] {
    var timeDic = [String:Int]()
    let dC = NSDateComponents()
    let cC = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

    if let hour = Int(currentCalendar.component(NSCalendarUnit.Hour, fromDate: fromDate)) {
        timeDic.append["hour":hour]
    }

    if let minutes = Int(currentCalendar.component(NSCalendarUnit.Minute, fromDate: fromDate)) {
        timeDic.append["minutes":minutes
    }
    return timeDic
}
```

Then you can call the keys to set a new NSDate if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution my classmate helped me to achieve

....

```
 let date6 = NSDateComponents()
    date6.hour = 17
    date6.minute = 3

    datesArray = [date2, date3, date4, date5, date6]

datesArray.sortInPlace {
        NSNumber(integer:($0.minute + ($0.hour * 60))).compare(NSNumber(integer: ($1.minute + ($1.hour * 60)))) == .OrderedAscending
    }
```

....

Comment: You do realize this has nothing to do with what you asked?

Comment: at the time my way which has some more code to it worked i just didnt paste all of it...but then i used yours sorry